Underlying sigma-algebra of a random process
random process is usually defined as a collection $(X_i)_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is some index set and each $X_i$ is a random variable $X_i:(\Omega,\mathcal{A})\rightarrow(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B})$. If each random variable $X_i$ of some random process acts on common measurable space $(\Omega_b,\mathcal{A}_b)$, underlying $\Omega$ of this random process is not $\Omega_b$, but in fact $\Omega\times\Omega\cdots$. Like if $X_i$ is a number of heads in $i$ coin tosses , underlying $\Omega$ of random process $(X_i)$ is not $\{H,T\}$, but $\{H,T\}^\infty$ (with corresponding $\sigma$-algebras). Am I right?
Some texts omit this fundmental concept and consider, for example this process, to live on $\{H,T\}$. I think this understanding is fine applications-wise, unless we start to think about mathematics of it. Some concepts, like filtrations, martingales etc. just do not make sense to me, if I am grasping this incorrectly. For example, if we think of a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}_n$ from some filtration of $\mathcal{A}$ as an information up to time $n$, the $\mathcal{A}_n$ has form $\mathcal{A_n}=\mathcal{P}(\{H,T\})\otimes \mathcal{P}(\{H,T\}) \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{P}(\{H,T\}) \otimes \{\emptyset,\{H,T\}\}\otimes \{\emptyset,\{H,T\}\} \cdots$.
Could somebody please tell me, if I am correct with this understanding?

You would be advised to try to make sense of filtrations, because doing so will answer your questions.  If you think you can dodge this effort, then can you give us a simple account of what the "corresponding sigma algebra" for ${H,T}^\infty$ would be and how you construct it?

No, I am completely satisfied with the "more complicated" concept, but surprised how many people omit which made me question myself.

If you want filtrations at all times $n$ to be subsets of the the same overall $\sigma$-algebra, then, yes, it will need to be something like the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on ${\cal X}^{\cal I}$, or in your more specific case, on $\{H, T\}^{\mathbb N}$.  This is the same as the product of all the Borel $\sigma$-algebras on the individual $\{H, T\}$, and it's determined by all the finite products.
Often, though, you don't need the entire process as a completed object and you can work with finite collections of $X_i$s, which only involve at most finite histories (and no history under independence), and so all the objects you need for formal reasoning are finite products and the entire process doesn't appear.
For example, if you want to say that every infinite sequence has zero probability, which sounds like a complete-process statement, the definition of the infinite product measures and topologies means that the statement is equivalent to saying there are finite subsequences with arbitrarily small products, and that can be proved without any reference to the infinite product as a thing in itself.
You see this with a more complicated index set in formal treatments of survival analysis using local martingales, which work with:

the collection of individual maps $X_t:\Omega\to {\mathbb R}$ for each $t\in[0,\infty)$, so $X_t(\omega)$ is the random value of today's $X_t$
the map $X:[0,\infty)\times \Omega \to {\mathbb R}$, so $X(t,\omega)$ is today's random value of $X$
the map $X:\Omega \to D[0,\infty)$, where $D[0,\infty)$ has one of the norms that make it separable, and $X(\omega)(t)$ is today's value for the random path $X(\omega)$

Most -- but not all -- of the proofs only need the first two. The third is needed mainly for results on convergence of estimators of a whole-path function of time to the truth plus a Gaussian process.
